# How can i render a route component in the parent component from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Suppose i have navigation bar component

```
<Nav />
```

I have all the routing logic inside this navigation bar component

When i click on a link the navigation happens but the component is loaded inside the navigation bar and not outside.
this is a image from http://localhost:3000/whiteboard , the whiteBoard component should render from root component where the logic of router is not written.check this [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-swanson-6pqr8?file=/src/App.js) to view the full code and working .

[image: App preview]

Comment: Hi, check my answer. I shared the files to be fixed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `<Switch> ... </Switch>` to `app.js` at the same level as `<Nav />`.

- nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = styled.nav`
  width: 20vw;
  border: black 1px solid;
  height: 100vh;
`;

const AppName = styled.h1`
  padding: 1em;
`;
const ListContainer = styled.ul``;
const ListItem = styled.li``;
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <NavBar>
      <AppName>Test</AppName>
      <ListContainer>
        <ListItem>
          <Link to="/">Draft</Link>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Link to="/notes">Notes</Link>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <Link to="/whiteboard">Whiteboard</Link>
        </ListItem>
      </ListContainer>
    </NavBar>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

- App.js

```
import Nav from "./components/nav";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/notes" component={Draft} />
          <Route path="/whiteboard" component={Whiteboard} />
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function Whiteboard() {
  return <h2>Whiteboard</h2>;
}

function Draft() {
  return <h2>Draft</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

- index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `<Switch>` statement with all the routes outside the `<Nav/>` component. It's not supposed to be in the navigation. In order for this to work, you should also make `<Router>` top-level (so that both `<Switch/>` and `<Link/>` are below the Router component so that they can access it's context), like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          ...
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this it is not rendering anything unless a hard refresh 
i have this  code in App.js
``` 
 <Router>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/notes" exact component={Notes} />
          <Route path="/whiteboard" exact component={Whiteboard}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```
and this nav.js
```
 <Router>
     <Link to="/Home">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/notes">Notes</Link>
      <Link to="/whiteboard">Whiteboard</Link>
</Router>
```

Comment: @HussamKhatib You don't need `<Router>` in nav.js